# Where should I store my underscore.js iterators?

Tags: javascript, module, iterator, global-variables, underscore.js

Say I want to have some "globals" (depicted with `?`) where I can store and then access the following functions:

```
?.parseInt = function (str) { return parseInt(str, 10); };
?.selected = function (x) { return x.selected; };
```

The usage would be for example to use with `map` or `filter` somewhere else:

```
var intArray = _.map(stringArray, ?.parseInt);
var selection = _.filter(myObjsHavingSelectedAttribute, ?.selected);
```

What should I put in place of `?`?

Comment: Note: I'm using Angular.js, but I'm also interested in a general plain JS or even jQuery idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choices are to either create your own namespace object or use an existing namespace object.

Creating your own namespace in plain JS would look like this:

```
var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};
myNamespace.parseInt = function (str) { return parseInt(str, 10); };
myNamespace.selected = function (x) { return x.selected; };
```

Using an existing namespace like the underscore namespace would look like this:

```
_.parseInt = function (str) { return parseInt(str, 10); };
_.selected = function (x) { return x.selected; };
```

Or, specific to underscore, you can make it both available at the top level of the underscore namespace and also available on underscore wrapper objects like this:

```
_.mixin({
    parseInt: function (str) { return parseInt(str, 10); },
    selected: function (x) { return x.selected; }
});
```

Using the jQuery namespace would look like this:

```
$.parseInt = function (str) { return parseInt(str, 10); };
$.selected = function (x) { return x.selected; };
```

Comment: You'd usually use [`_.mixin`](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin) to add things to Underscore to make sure that all of `_.f(x)`, `_(x).f()`, and chaining work properly. Probably doesn't matter here but good habits are good habits.

Comment: @muistooshort - added the `_.mixin()` option.

Comment: Is it really a good idea to "pollute" the `_` namespace with these methods? What do you think about using `_.mixin({ myNamespace: { parseInt: ..., selected: ... } });`? (if it works at all?!)

Comment: Anytime you use someone else's namespace, you run a slight chance that someone else is trying to do the same thing with the same names, but generally a smaller chance of a problem than using the top level global namespace.  There is no perfect solution here so you're just picking an option with lower odds of a conflict.  I personally wouldn't double namespace it (put it two levels down) because that starts to interfere with the writing and reading of the code more than I think is worth it, but that's just a personal opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can really put them anywhere you like.

If I've understood your question correctly, your concerns are basically those of handling namespace.

1. **Loosing them if they're overwritten.** This is easy to manage on a small project but if you have a lot of programmers working and everyone likes to use `zzz` as a global object somebody's functions will be overwritten.

   your code

   ```
   zzz = {
     makeWorldPeace : function() { 
       // TODO: implement this 
     }    
   };
   ```

   your friend's code

   ```
   zzz = {
     makePizza : function() { 
       // ... 
     }
   };
   ```

   If you try to call your function `zzz.makeWorldPeace()` you'll get a `TypeError` that says `Object has no method makeWorldPeace`.
2. **Having them overwritten by similar code.** Same example as before, but this time your friend's code is this

   ```
   zzz = {
     makeWorldPeace: function() {
       killAllHumans()
     }
   };
   ```

   This might not be your original intent.

There are many patterns for namespace in JavaScript. Most people try to do the following things to avoid conflicts.

1. Pick a good name for your root object. `_utils`, `JSHelpers`, whatever will be unique within your project.
2. Manage your variable scope well by always using `var`.
3. If you want to be good and careful, make sure you don't have any memory leaks, or you're using large chunks of code with other large chunks of code, wrap things in a self executing function like this

   ```
   (function(export){
      var intermediateFunction = function(){};
      var zzz = { /* all the things */ };
      export.zzz = zzz;
   })(window)

   console.log(intermediateFunction); // outputs: undefined
   ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Make sure you use `var` inside that IIFE, otherwise it won't have the effect you described.